# String() variable in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to modify a program where there is a variable that stores all the specified file types in a `String()` variable. What I would like to do is to somehow append to this variable in any way if I want to search another directory or just grab another individual file. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
//Grab files from a directory with the *.txt or *.log as specified in the Combo Box
Dim strFiles As String()
strFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtSource.Text, cmbtype.SelectedItem, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

**EDIT: Edited to include code snippet used.**

```
Dim strFiles As String()
Dim listFiles As List(Of String)(strFiles)

If (cmbtype.SelectedItem = "All") Then
    //Do stuff

     For index As Integer = 1 To cmbtype.Items.Count - 1
         Dim strFileTypes As String() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtSource.Text, cmbtype.Items(index), IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
     Next

    //Exit Sub
Else
    listFiles.Add(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtSource.Text, cmbtype.SelectedItem, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToString())
End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you're using a `String()` which is an array of `String` instances.  Arrays are not well suited for dynamically growing structures.  A much better type is `List(Of String)`.  It is used in very similar manners to a `String()` but has a handy `Add` and `AddRange` method for appending data to the end.

```
Dim strFiles As New List(Of String)()
strFiles.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtSource.Text, cmbtype.SelectedItem, I
```

O.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

Answer (score 1):

```
dim listFiles as list(of string)
listFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtSource.Text, cmbtype.SelectedItem, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList()
listFiles.Add("..\blah\...\")
```

Comment: +1: I was just typing something similar and then it popped up 1 new answer.

Comment: I don't see a .ToList() option.

Comment: do you have 
    Import System.Linq
?

Comment: I suppose if your using .Net 2.0 that wouldn't work.

Luckly List(of T) will take an array in a constructor overload.

Dim strFiles As String() 
strFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtSource.Text, cmbtype.SelectedItem, IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

dim listOfFiles as new list(of string)(strFiles)
listOfFiles.Add("..\file\..")

Comment: Tried to do that, but got an error about 'array bounds cannot be in type specifiers'. I'm trying to do this in Visual Studio 2008 with .Net 3.5

Comment: Sounds like you've got the generic type specifier and the constructor mixed up.

It should be Dim alist As New List(of Some_Type)(Constructor_Args_Here)

Can you post the snippet you tried?